# Handling expired json web token with passportjs in nodejs express api

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jwt, passport.js

I have a working transaction of the json web token from my express api to my client local storage.  Now I am trying to implement a refresh token to handle issuing a new token when the client's access token is expired.  My idea is to have the access token life be 1 hour and the refresh token be 30 days.  But my issue is that when the passportjs authentication happens and attempts to pull the token from the header, if the token is expired I am not even getting into the passport authentication method to handle it.  Would anybody have some input/assistance on how I can handle this?

This is my passport authentication in my express route:

```
const opts = {
    jwtFromRequest : ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderWithScheme('Bearer'),
    secretOrKey : 'secret',
    passReqToCallback: true
};

    //This is the method I can't get in that is just returning a 401 on expired tokens
    //unless I add to the options: ignoreExpiration.
    passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts, function(req, jwtPayload, done) {
        jwt.verify(jwtPayload, 'secret', function(err, decoded) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log(decoded);
            }
        });
        userService.getUserById(jwtPayload.id).then((user) => {
            user ? done(null, user) : done(null, false);
        });
    }));
```

In the above code I am looking for a way to handle the expired tokens, if that is the correct way to do so.  But ideally check if the current token being passed in is expired.  Then if it is, check a collection of refresh tokens for the token containing the user id.  If it is found, somehow extend the expiration on the token that was sent in.  Would like to hear everybody's input if they think that is a good way to handle it, or if it can be improved or am I just going about this all wrong?

Comment: If the json web token is expired, do you need to be sending it over at all? In the case where you need to refresh, just sent the refresh token, and get back a new json web token. See here for example: https://auth0.com/blog/refresh-tokens-what-are-they-and-when-to-use-them/